# ¿Cómo puedo editar un portafolio web que saqué de la página de Github de otro usuario?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

esta es mí primer pregunta aquí en Stack Overflow y pues la verdad soy nuevo en esto de la programación. Mí situación es la siguiente: estoy armando mi portafolio web para buscar trabajo y me encontré con uno de código libre que saqué de un repositorio en Github, pero a la hora de que quiero editarlo y poner mí propia información no sé cómo, el creador dejó un README pero la verdad es que no lo entendí muy bien y de tantos archivos y carpetas que tiene no sé a cuál moverle. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo editarlo?

Les dejo el link al repositorio de donde lo saqué para que vean los archivos y carpetas que trae: https://github.com/saadpasta/developerFolio

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que parte de las instrucciones que figuran ahi no entendiste?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que necesitas hacer segun el README, es colocar un archivo propio de `portfolio.js`, o igualmente editarlo, esta en la carpeta `src`.

- Clona el proyecto a tu PC.
- Abre la carpeta del proyecto en un editor de texto.
- Encuentra la carpeta `SRC` y abrela.
- Dentro encontraras un archivo llamado `portfolio.js`
- Editalo con tus datos o haz uno nuevo y colocalo en esa ubicacion (carpeta src).

Y practicamente seria todo, una vez colocando tus datos en ese archivo el sitio lo mostrara.

Comment: Listo, ya agregué los cambios con mí propia información. Ahora cómo lo visualizo en el navegador? Trato de abrir el archivo index.html pero simplemente la pantalla se muestra en blanco.

Comment: Tienes que abrirlo con algun editor de texto, por ejemplo yo lo abriria con Visual Studio Code y despues agregar live server a VS Code para asi poder trabajar "en vivo" en el proyecto.